# PR2 hydro tuckarms

Tags: gazebo, ros-hydro, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just testing the pr2 simulation in hydro and I noticed that I cannot even do tuckarms. Is this normal? something changed in the way you do tuckarms now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174370/pr2-hydro-tuckarms/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-29**:
Can you be more specific about the error you encounter when trying to use tuckarms in Hydro?

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-06-29**:
It's just that in groovy there is the folder =/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_common_actions/pr2_tuck_arms_action= and not in hydro. So I cannot do the tuckarms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Missing a particular folder just indicates that you don't have the corresponding package installed.

I think the bigger issue here is that the pr2_tuckarm package probably isn't released for Hydro. See http://answers.ros.org/question/178864/how-to-run-tuckarm-on-hydro/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0